# Is a $C^{1,1}$ function a viscosity solution?

Tags: viscosity-solutions

Assume $F(A)$ is a degenerate elliptic operator. Let $u$ be the limit of a smooth sequence $({u_n})$ and $F(D^2 u_n)=f_n\ge 0$ with $(f_n)$ converging uniformly to $0$. If we know that $u$ is $C^{1,1}$ (i.e., $Du$ is Lipschitz), how to prove that $u$ is  a viscosity solution of $F(D^2 u)=0$? Is there any reference?

Comment: Try https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9207212

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you tell me which page?